# Launched my ERC20 contract on both Ethereum and PulseChain, when updating fees on Pulsechain i recieve this error? Please help

Tags: solidity, ether, fees

```
invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
```

I get this message when updating the fees on buys/sells. Can anyone help? This is already deployed and live so I cannot change anything in remix, also, every other function on the contracts works fine bar my “update fees”

Comment: This is an error from the library you use to access the blockchain. Probably some JS code. Impossible to say more with this information.